# How can this be done with the same result using mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on porting some code over from mysql_ to mysqli_ equivalents, however I stumbled accross something that doesn't seem to be a straight conversion:

I have the following code

```
if($field_flags == false) {
    for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) {
        $field_flags[$j] = mysql_field_flags($result, $j);
        if(strpos($field_flags[$j], 'not_null') !== false) {
            $field_flags[$j] = false;
        } else {
            $field_flags[$j] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And I am having trouble porting it as the new method "mysqli_fetch_field_direct" doesn't seem to be as straightforward.

Could someone please assist me with porting the above code.  Essentially, I am checking if the field allows nulls or not.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_field_direct` returns an object. Hence you can't use strpos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `mysqli_fetch_field_direct` returns an `object`, where as `mysql_field_flags` retuns a `string`. Hence your direct use of `strpos` won't work.

```
if($field_flags == false) {
    for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) {
        $field_flags[$j] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $j);
        if(strpos($field_flags[$j]->flags, 'NOT_NULL') !== false) {
           //Do something here
        } else {
           //Do something else
    }
}
```

More here on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php)