# How to get Fields Flags Name with SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Actually I want to Display Flags Name of all fields which is belongs to a table. This is Our script, from which i am performing this action.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
mysql_select_db("DatabaseName"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table_Name"); 
$fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
for ($i=0; $i < $fields; $i++) { 
    $flags = mysql_field_flags($result, $i); echo $flags . "<br>";
} 
mysql_free_result($result); 
mysql_close();
?>
```

This works well, but the problem is this script is `mysql` version but i want `mysqli` version of the script. Is there any way to perform the same action by `mysqli` version of the script.

and also the question is - this script is using `offset` value in for loop. Is there any to way to display `flags` value without `offset value`

OR Insetead of using `offset value` can we use field name ?

Comment: the is the problem with `mysqli_num_fields` ?

Comment: @robert Becuase from starting i am using`mysqli` version in our application.,

Comment: see that http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will fetch the flags

```
$mysqli=new mysqli('localhost','root','','database');
$result=$mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM table');
while($meta = mysqli_fetch_field($result)){
    $flags=$meta->flags;
    echo $flags."<br>";
    print_r(get_flag1($flags));
    echo '<br/>';
    print_r(get_flag2($flags));
    echo '<br/>';
}

function get_flag1($flag_value){
    $result['NOT_NULL_FLAG'] = 1&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['PRI_KEY_FLAG'] = 2&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG'] = 4&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['BLOB_FLAG'] = 16&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['UNSIGNED_FLAG'] = 32&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['ZEROFILL_FLAG'] = 64&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['BINARY_FLAG'] = 128&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['ENUM_FLAG'] = 256&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG'] = 512&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['TIMESTAMP_FLAG'] = 1024&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['SET_FLAG'] = 2048&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['NUM_FLAG'] = 32768&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['PART_KEY_FLAG'] = 16384&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['GROUP_FLAG'] = 32768&$flag_value?1:0;
    $result['UNIQUE_FLAG'] = 65536&$flag_value?1:0;
    return $result;
}

function get_flag2($flag_value){
    if(1&$flag_value)
        $result[]='NOT_NULL_FLAG';
    if(2&$flag_value)
        $result[]='PRI_KEY_FLAG';
    if(4&$flag_value)
        $result[]='UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG';
    if(16&$flag_value)
        $result[]='BLOB_FLAG';
    if(32&$flag_value)
        $result[]='UNSIGNED_FLAG';
    if(64&$flag_value)
        $result[]='ZEROFILL_FLAG';
    if(128&$flag_value)
        $result[]='BINARY_FLAG';
    if(256&$flag_value)
        $result[]='ENUM_FLAG';
    if(512&$flag_value)
        $result[]='AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG';
    if(1024&$flag_value)
        $result[]='TIMESTAMP_FLAG';
    if(2048&$flag_value)
        $result[]='SET_FLAG';
    if(32768&$flag_value)
        $result[]='NUM_FLAG';
    if(16384&$flag_value)
        $result[]='PART_KEY_FLAG';
    if(32768&$flag_value)
        $result[]='GROUP_FLAG';
    if(65536&$flag_value)
        $result[]='UNIQUE_FLAG';
    return $result;
}
```

**how it work**

using `&` with these values to check the wanted flag it will output 0 if the flag is off or the value if the flag is on

for example to check `UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG` use `$flags_value&4` it will output 0 if it off or 4 if it on

NOT_NULL_FLAG = 1
   PRI_KEY_FLAG = 2
   UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG = 4
   BLOB_FLAG = 16
   UNSIGNED_FLAG = 32
   ZEROFILL_FLAG = 64
   BINARY_FLAG = 128
   ENUM_FLAG = 256
   AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG = 512
   TIMESTAMP_FLAG = 1024
   SET_FLAG = 2048
   NUM_FLAG = 32768
   PART_KEY_FLAG = 16384
   GROUP_FLAG = 32768
   UNIQUE_FLAG = 65536

**explain**

the flag is binary number like `10110011` every bit represent a flag state on or off 0 for off and 1 for on

for example to check unique key flag it's the third bit so when you use the and operator between `100B` and `10110011B` the result will be all zero except the wanted bit

so if this bit is zero all the number will be zero and this mean false to php

and if it's one the result will be `100B` in php any number not zero will mean true to php

Comment: this gives us  `flags value`. how can i convert them in flags name.

Comment: But also the problem is `flags values` does't match with the value whatever you written above.

Comment: sorry for that you should use `&` with this number not `==`

Comment: afterall still we are getting `values`.

Comment: i explained what this value mean

Comment: is there any way to display flags name istead of value..?

Comment: wait i will give you a function that take flag value and return flags but do you need all of these flags ?

Comment: done for all flags remove the ones you don't need to make you code more clear

Comment: if you don't want the `_FLAG` at the end of the names you can search for it and replace with nothing i mean using IDE

Answer (score 0):

Try something inline with this

```
if($field_flags == false) {
    for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) {
        $field_flags[$j] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $j);
        if(strpos($field_flags[$j]->flags, 'NOT_NULL') !== false) {
           //Do something here
        } else {
           //Do something else
    }
}
```

or see this

[How can this be done with the same result using mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014378/how-can-this-be-done-with-the-same-result-using-mysqli)

Comment: Actually This is not the answer what i am looking..for..Please see the quesion one more time.